# Send notification when PostgreSQL block is detected

Tags: sql, postgresql

As my system scales, we're running into blocking issues due to [locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html). That is, concurrent transactions are holding conflicting locks, which is causing transactions to wait until the locks are released.

I have a [simple SQL statement](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras/blob/main/commands/blocking.js) for viewing blocks. I would love to setup a mechanism for sending myself a notification (email, slack message, etc.) whenever this script returns at least one item. Is there anyway to do this?

I found a [NOTIFY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) command but I haven't seen a good example for my use case.

Comment: that is not simple and a select usually don't lock

Comment: You can write a client program that performs your check regularly and notifies you. You cannot do that from inside the database.

Comment: If you want to send an email using js on Heroku, you should tag your question that way.  That the contents of the email is about PostgreSQL doesn't make any difference to what the solution is.

Comment: @jjanes this isn't specific to Heroku. I'm just using their blocking script.

Comment: I would first spend some time on the root cause, these locks. What is going on, why does it happen, what is wrong in the application?

Comment: With enough effort, you can do this in the database, probably using pl/perl or pl/pythonu.  But I wouldn't do it that way, but rather from outside the database.  So then you would have two questions "How do I query PostgreSQL from <my favorite language>?" and "How do I send email from <my favorite language>?"